# Tensorflow quantization: Array output does not have MinMax information

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am attempting to create a Tensorflow quantized model for inference with the Coral USB Accelerator. Here is a minimal standalone example of my issue:

```
import sys

import tensorflow as tf

CKPT = "a/out.ckpt"
TFLITE = "a/out.tflite"

args = sys.argv[1:]
if 0 == len(args):
    print("Options are 'train' or 'save'")
    exit(-1)
cmd = args[0]

if cmd not in ["train", "save"]:
    print("Options are 'train' or 'save'")
    exit(-1)

tr_in = [[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]]
tr_out = [[1.0], [1.0], [0.0], [0.0]]

nn_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 2), name="input")

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 1], stddev=0.1))
B = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1]))

nn_out = tf.nn.relu6(tf.matmul(nn_in, W) + B, name="output")

if "train" == cmd:
    tf.contrib.quantize.create_training_graph(quant_delay=0)
    nn_act = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 1), name="actual")
    diff = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(nn_act - nn_out, 2))
    update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(
            learning_rate=0.0001,
        )
        goal = optimizer.minimize(diff)
else:
    tf.contrib.quantize.create_eval_graph()

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init)

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    try:
        saver.restore(session, CKPT)
    except BaseException as e:
        print("While trying to restore: {}".format(str(e)))

    if "train" == cmd:
        for epoch in range(2):
            _, d = session.run([goal, diff], feed_dict={
                nn_in: tr_in,
                nn_act: tr_out,
            })
            print("Loss: {}".format(d))
        saver.save(session, CKPT)
    elif "save" == cmd:
        converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_session(
            session, [nn_in], [nn_out],
        )
        converter.inference_type = tf.lite.constants.QUANTIZED_UINT8
        input_arrays = converter.get_input_arrays()
        converter.quantized_input_stats = {input_arrays[0] : (0.0, 1.0)}
        tflite_model = converter.convert()
        with open(TFLITE, "wb") as f:
            f.write(tflite_model)
```

Assuming you have a directory called "a", this can be ran with:

```
python example.py train
python example.py save
```

The "train" step should work fine, but when attempting to export the quantized tflite file, I get the following:

```
...
2019-05-14 14:03:44.032912: F tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/quantize.cc:144] Array output does not have MinMax information, and is not a constant array. Cannot proceed with quantization.
Aborted
```

My goal is to successfully run the "save" step and end up with a trained quantized model. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tricky bug in TFLiteConverter:

- For the conversion to the quantized model format in requires additional nodes (with MinMax info) for each (almost each) mathematical operation node.
- Such additional nodes are added *create_eval_graph* function **after** corresponding operations.
- But during conversion to the TFLite format converter only takes into account the nodes between *inputs* and *outputs* (inclusively). Therefor additional node (with MinMax info) after your *nn_out* is "thrown away" in this case, which leads to the mentioned conversion error :(

That bug doesn't appear if you build a classification network which usually ends up with softmax layer (which doesn't require MinMax info). But for the regression networks this is a problem. I use the following workaround.

Add additional (actually meaningless) operation after your output layer before calling the *create_eval_graph* function, like this:

```
nn_out = tf.minimum(nn_out, 1e6)
```

You can use any arbitrary number (for the second argument) just much bigger than expected output layer values upper bound. It works perfectly in my case.